# Autoplay video on mobile? Facebook Home does it. What am I missing?

Tags: android, facebook, html, video, autoplay

I'm trying to add a video to my homepage in replace of a slider.

I understand how and why mobile devices disable autoplay.

However FacebookHome and Youtube will autoplay on mobile.

https://bg-bg.facebook.com/home

I'm using HTML5 method but it's not autoplaying on mobile. looking at Facebook Home, the code looks similar so I'm not understanding.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<video width="100%"  poster="poster.jpg" loop="1" autoplay="1">

 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">

</video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Autoplay on most mobile platforms (Android, iOS) gets blocked to avoid
>   poor user experiences - video should only play following a user
>   action. You can usually work around it by triggering the play() on
>   another event (eg the onloaded event)

Facebook Home provides a video type extension `.ogv` which worked on FireFox Beta only (I tried both Google chrome And Android default browser, but it just shows the poster image)

```
<video poster="Poster.jpg" autoplay="1" loop="1">
<source src="myVideo.mp4">
<source src="myVideo.ogv">
</video>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEGKN/)

Another solution is to add `event listener` to trigger the video to be played when the user clicks on the video element

```
<video id="myVideo" poster="Poster.jpg">
<source src="myVideo.mp4">
<source src="myVideo.ogv">
</video>
```

JS:

```
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEGKN/1/) Works with Firefox beta (Inside windows) But for in Android Browser it calls Video Player App to play the video

Resources:

- [Ogg - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg)
- [Android webview html5 video autoplay not working on android 4.0.3: Best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718186/2151050)
- [Making HTML5 Video work on Android phones](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/0/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/)