# HTML 5 Video does not start automatically in the Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android-webview, html5-video

I want play html5 video in the android webview.My html file is locate in localhost.In the browser,video is start to play automatically.no need click play button.But in android webview it is not start until click play button.

Html :

```
    <body onload="init()">

        <div id="pagewrap">

            <video id="player" width="700" height="390" controls="control"  > 
               <source id="video_src"     src='http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/pd16/media/3597709025001/201406/3659/3597709025001_3636330355001_ff.mp4' type="video/mp4">
            </video>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Java Scrip :

```
       function init(){
            var player = document.getElementById('player');
            player.play();

        }
```

Java:

```
        onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ......

             WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

             mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
             mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.2:81/video_stream_app_view.php");


       }
```

Comment: follow this link for your answer https://gist.github.com/aprock/5913322

Comment: maybe changing the phone's setting in browser's Labs menu would affect webViews as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier for you to just use the "autoplay" attribute of the  tag ?

Comment: it should be the comment rather then answer

Comment: I'm talking about adding autoplay to the video tag as :video id="player" width="700" height="390" controls="control" autoplay

Answer (score 0):

By default, autoplay for videos is disabled for mobile web-browsers. It's a W3C standard. More information can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107878/autoplay-video-on-mobile-facebook-home-does-it-what-am-i-missing).