# Android: "Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: android, ios, html, html5-video

I'm working on a HTML5 video player automation(test page is a html page). I tried to call `myPlayer.Play()` through Javascript.  On Android, however, I got this error:

> Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture.

after sending a `Play()` request.

I know `autoplay` is disabled on lots of devices on purpose to save users bandwidth. But the first time `Play()` seems also needed the user gesture. What is the workaround for this so that I can automate testing for the player device?

Comment: Not a duplicate, as the question has a specific answer in the context of an Android WebView.

Answer (score 45):

You can disable this security function. For example:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Available in API versions 17 and above

[More info see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946183/android-webview-html5-video-autoplay-not-working-on-android-4-0-3)

Comment: After one night looking for a solution, this answer just save my life. Thx.

Comment: This is a more useful answer than the duplicates tagged above.

Comment: It's awesome. Thanks.