# AutoPlay Youtube frame API on Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

Impossible to autoplay youtube videos in an Android webview by using youtube iframe API. Does someone knows if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in [Mobile Considerations](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations), functions and parameters such as `autoplay`, `playVideo()`, `loadVideoById()` won't work in all mobile environments due to the restrictions wherein HTML5 `<video>` element only allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a user interaction.

You may, however, try the given suggestions in the following SO posts and might work for you:

- [Youtube Api android autostart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354621/youtube-api-android-autostart)

  > You can use [`loadVideo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)) method which loads and plays the specified video. And, there is also the [`cueVideo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#cueVideo(java.lang.String)) method, which adds the video to the playlist, but does not automatically start playing the video.
- [Android webview html5 video autoplay not working on android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946183/android-webview-html5-video-autoplay-not-working-on-android-4-0-3)

  > You can usually work around it by triggering the `play()` on another event (eg the `onloaded` event).

Hope that helps!