# work around to autoplay video while the app has set setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true)

Tags: javascript, html, video, autoplay

now i have a page can be accessed in some in other app's spotlight, in that page I need to autoplay a video , it works well in normal browser ,and also well in some app that set to allow autoplay. But if there any possibility to work around even the app has set `WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946183/android-webview-html5-video-autoplay-not-working-on-android-4-0-3/16718186#16718186  here i find a solution, but not work for me

Comment: Videos with sound cannot autoplay on Android or iOS. You can set `muted` in the setup of your video tag to have silent autoplay (maybe place a notice above video saying "muted: click to listen") where click function does something like `video.mute = false;`.

Comment: I have already set the necessary attribute, `mute` ,`playsinline`,etc.