# Xamarin Forms (PCL) Youtube Player loading in a WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, youtube

We have YouTube trailers that we want to run on our Xamarin Forms (PCL) project.

We have try'd everything but somehow there is not a good Youtube player out there :(

So now we are loading the Youtube trailers in a WebView so that it runs on the Android + iOS.

This is how we load the trailers in our WebView component:

```
var apiRequest = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/GYmm9qNwd_s?html5=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=1";

var webView = new WebView();
webView.Source = apiRequest;
webView.MinimumWidthRequest = 200;
webView.MinimumHeightRequest = 200;
webView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
webView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

var stackLayout = new StackLayout();

stackLayout.Children.Add(webView);

stackLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
stackLayout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

grid.Children.Add(stackLayout);

this.Content = grid;
```

**But somehow the Trailer is running on iOS and Android but the Autoplay is not working and the related movies still show up!**

[image: Screenshot1-ShowingControls]

[image: Screenshot2-RelMoviesStillShow]

So my question is :

1. Is there a way to set the Autoplay on the Xamarin Forms platforms?
2. Why does the autoplay function won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay on most mobile platforms (Android, iOS) gets blocked to avoid poor user experiences - video should only play following a user action.
Like in Andriod, Auto-play is disabled since Android SDK 17.
You can check this question to get more information [Android webview html5 video autoplay not working on android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946183/android-webview-html5-video-autoplay-not-working-on-android-4-0-3/16718186)